# Will I lose my Windows 8 license if I install Windows 7 or Linux?

Tags: windows-8

I just bought a laptop with Windows 8 pre-installed ( updated to 8.1 update 1 August update ) . The key is not given on bottom of case nor a recovery disc is provided . The key is something embedded into laptop . Will I lose this license I I install Windows 7 or Ubuntu Linux ? I am not liking Windows 8 now but may came back to it again later .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Technically speaking, no. You do not lose the key, but in windows 7, the license key doesn't work, so you will need to buy a windows 7 license. In order to come back to this windows, you need to retreive the key first, and write it down. Nirsoft has a tool called ProduKey which can read the key from your computer. Do this first, and write it down so you can install Windows 8 later.

Alternatively, make an image of how your system is now, so you can restore that and get everything you currently have setup. (this means all your drivers are also installed). Restoring an image does not require your windows serial number.

Comment: I made a image before I activated Windows . Does this image include key ?

Comment: It does, but if you have activated windows AFTER you made the image, your image will not have an activated windows, and will likely not activate again. You should make a new image of the activated windows.

Comment: But I activated Windows 8 and updated to Windows 8.1 . Will the image be of Windows 8 or 8.1 ?

Comment: Found it . It will be of 8 not 8.1 .

Comment: The image is whatever your pc was when you made the image.

Comment: Like I said I created image before activation then I activated it and updated to 8.1 . Now I create recovery image  it will be 8 with key right ?

Comment: An image will save the state your computer is in right now. If it is windows 8.1, your image will be 8.1. If its linux, your image will be linux.